# Saving Auto-Incrementing line number in Inline field Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have the following model as an inline field in another model:

```
class route_ordering(models.Model): 
   route_id = models.ForeignKey(route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   activity_id = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   day = models.IntegerField()
   order = models.IntegerField()
```

And in the admin.py:

```
class RouteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = (RouteOrderingInline,)
```

I would like to make "order" self-incrementing from one, so it will be auto filled when I go to the Django admin panel (in the first line order=1 , then order-2 etc.)

I know you can use Default to set an autofilled value, but I want it to increment by itself.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't guarantee this will work, and I'm not able to test out right now, but I think you can pass in a generator to your default value arg.

```
define increment():
    return range(1, 1000)
```

And wherever your passing in a default just call `next(increment())`

Sorry I can't provide a more detailed example, I'm writing this on my phone XD, but I think that should work.

Comment: I aleady have a Autofield, which is the ID. + This value isn't unique for every line in the table, It should start from 1 every time you open a new form

Comment: Interesting, and you only need this for the django admin?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand, you want the number to default to 1 on new forms, and increment every time you save a record right?

Comment: On each form , there are 10 inline fields - which means 10 lines you can add info through. at each inline field I got a "order" field. i want that for the first Inline line it will be defulted to 1. on the second row, defulted to 2, etc.